# Cannot find dependencies when executing an assembly published by dotnet publish

Tags: c#, .net-core

I wrote a .NET Core 2.0 console application. Publish using `dotnet publish`, But there was an error during execution:

### Run failed

**Compile project**

```sh
dotnet publish src\Bucket.CLI\Bucket.CLI.csproj -c Release --self-contained false
```

**Execute program**

- `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish`

```sh
dotnet Bucket.CLI.dll
```

**Prompt error:**

```sh
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Bucket.CLI.dep
s.json) was not found:
    package: 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages', version: '4.5.1'
    path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'
```

### Run successfully

But, if I specify a `--runtime`, then no error will occur：

**Compile project**

```sh
dotnet publish src\Bucket.CLI\Bucket.CLI.csproj -c Release --self-contained false -r win-x64
```

**Execute program**

- `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win-x64\publish`

```sh
dotnet Bucket.CLI.dll
```

The program works fine.

What could be caused by this?

---

If I add the post to add: `Bucket.CLI.runtimeconfig.dev.json` Then the program can run successfully. But this does not work. There are some others way?

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
      "C:\\Users\\menghanyu\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
      "C:\\Users\\menghanyu\\.nuget\\packages",
      "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I add `--runtime` to compile there is no `Bucket.CLI.runtimeconfig.dev.json` The program is also running successful.

I am very confused, why is this happening?

---

### csproj file

- `src/Bucket/Bucket.csproj (.net standard2.0)`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>0.3.7250.21600</FileVersion>
    <Version>0.3.0+source</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.6.0-preview7.19362.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Compression" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Assets\Schema\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Assets\Signature\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

- `src/Bucket.CLI/Bucket.CLI.csproj (.net core 2.0)`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>Bucket.CLI.Program</StartupObject>
    <Version>0.3.0+source</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>0.3.7250.21600</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Bucket\Bucket.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="bucket">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="bucket.bat">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

- `src/Directory.Build.props (public)`

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsTestProject>$(MSBuildProjectName.Contains('Tests'))</IsTestProject>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)stylecop.json" Link="stylecop.json" />
    <Reference Include="GameBox.Console">
        <HintPath>..\..\lib\GameBox.Console\GameBox.Console.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GameBox.Semver">
        <HintPath>..\..\lib\GameBox.Semver\GameBox.Semver.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" PrivateAssets="all" Version="3.1.0-beta3-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" PrivateAssets="all" Version="2.9.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" Version="7.14.0.8411">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(IsTestProject)' == 'true'">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)analysis.test.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.6.1">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.11.0-rc1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.0.0-beta4" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.0.0-beta4" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)analysis.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
</Project>
```

- `.NET Core SDK:`

```sh
.NET Core SDK:
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  95a0a61858
```

Comment: can you share the csproj file?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have re-edited the content and attached the csproj used.

Comment: Reference to related github issue - https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3903

Comment: I get the exact same error with a project targetting netcoreapp3.1, and same output, same version of CodePages and refers to netcoreapp2.0. I have no reference anywhere in my project repository to CodePages.

Comment: That said, my builds work on a separate `dotnet build` step, then `dotnet publish` with `--no-build`. If I just run publish and let it build in the same command, then the problem goes away.